# How to use multiple canvas contexts?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I would like to use `experimental-webgl`, and the `2d` canvas context also. After I've drawn the 3d objects, I want to draw some 2d objects over it.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need a separate canvas. You can put the other canvas over the first one, this is not considered bad practice.

Comment: It might still be relevant to know that some browsers don't implement the compositing of the WebGL canvas and surrounding elements in a very efficient way (i.e. taking the image from OpenGL and then compositing on the CPU, then sending it back out to the GPU), and depending on how complicated the 2D stuff is that you're trying to do (i.e. just drawing some bitmaps for the GUI), it might be worth considering doing that through the WebGL canvas as well. Drawing 2D stuff in WebGL should simply be a matter of setting up the right transformations and perhaps disabling depth-testing

Answer (score 16):

You cannot use multiple contexts for one canvas element. In WebKit, this is explicitly mentioned [in the source](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/html/HTMLCanvasElement.cpp&exact_package=chromium&l=150):

```
// A Canvas can either be "2D" or "webgl" but never both.
```

If you do request another context, you get `null`:

```c
    if ((type == "webkit-3d") ||
        (type == "experimental-webgl")) {
        if (m_context && !m_context->is3d())
            return 0;
```

(So if you request a 3D context when you already have another context, you get `null`.)

What you probably want is two canvas elements - one for 3D stuff and the other one for 2D stuff. If you place them over each other, they act as two layers, and you can draw on each canvas independently.

Comment: An update HTMLCanvasElement.cpp file location: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/main/Source/core/html/HTMLCanvasElement.cpp

Comment: Updated reference to the [comment in the WebKit source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/refs/heads/main/Source/core/html/canvas/CanvasRenderingContext.h#54)